# Adding words to ArrayList with HashMap values in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrenthashmap

I have a class like this, and I am trying to write a loop which would use the strings for each entry in the lemmas ConcurrentHashMap ( get the string stored in value), split them by space into separate words, and then add these words into the corpus ArrayList.

```
package pipeline;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import helpers.JSONIOHelper;

public class B3DescriptiveStatistics {

    private static void startCreatingStatistics(String filePath) {
        System.out.println("Loading file...");      
                
        JSONIOHelper JSONIO = new JSONIOHelper(); 
        JSONIO.LoadJSON(filePath); 

        ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> lemmas = JSONIO.GetLemmasFromJSONStructure(); 
        
        ArrayList<String> corpus = new ArrayList<String>();
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> counts = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
        
//      lemmas.forEach( (string values, integer) -> corpus.add(string values) ?;
        
        for(String word : lemmas.split(" ")) {
            corpus.add(word);
        }   
    }
```

so my problem is how to get the string values and include them in my for loop?

Comment: Where are your words? In the key or the value of the map? Note the fact that it's a concurrent hash map is irrelevant for your question, you're handling List / Map (no matter the implementation)

Comment: If the words were in the values, then it would look something like this: `lemmas.forEach((k, v) -> corpus.addAll(Arrays.asList(v.split(" "))));`

Comment: It gives me an error, 'The method add String in the type ArrayList <String> is not applicable for the arguments (String[]).